# Downloaded file delete permanently from the android device

Tags: java, android, download, delete-file, internal-storage

I am developing an app, that use to download a zip file from ftp server to external space & next the downloaded zip,extract into internal safe memory anybody can not access and then delete the downloaded zip file using 
this code:

```
File tempZip = new File(zipFile);
tempZip.delete();
```

When testing with Huawei and LG devices, the downloaded and deleted zip files can be found in the devices download area and also the deleted zip are showing as just hidden item(can't open) in the area that I used to download. Can someone give me a strong solution to this issue ?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: File tempZip = new File(zipFile);
                if(tempZip.exists()) {
                    SharedPreferenceManager.getString(SharedPreferenceKeys.RECENT_DOWNLOAD,  tempZip.getName());
                    tempZip.delete();
                }   Awais, Do you need the downloading part also ?

Comment: you mean to delete downloaded file from Download Manager too?

Comment: Yes Awais ,also I need to permanently delete it, even without showing deleted zip's hidden file(only with huawei and LG phones) that can see with USB connectivity from downloaded area. I am trying to paste my whole code to here ,,but couldn't.Sorry about that.

Comment: Awais, the things that can see from the USB connectivity are not hidden zip,and luckily we cant copy it using USB connectivity,,they are just viewing as files . Apologies for my mistake. but I need to off that deleted file viewing also.

Comment: Sorry but I can't quite understand you
do you have Facebook or WhatsApp, so I can help you out? :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94599/discussion-between-charitha-amarasinghe-and-awais-king).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322531/permanently-delete-files-android, which does not have a substantive answer.